How to change "Choose File" and "No file is chosen"
I need to change two text in the input, the project uses bootstrap 5, I also need to save all bootstrap styles when changing the texts, how can this be done (I found how to change the choose file, but for the second text there is no)?

You forgot the code  to show what the problem is ... But i'm guessing that you are asking to change the default input text set by the browser, is it ?

Do you mean like this?  (potential duplicate)

@David there is using jquery, is it possible do it without it or not?

@CriticalError: It's certainly possible to not use jQuery.  What have you tried?

@David i tried this, but it's do not change both texts, tried your answer, it's worked, but i would like to do it most clear, than using jquery

@CriticalError: Is the problem that you're just not familiar with what that jQuery code is doing?  There are only 2 jQuery operations being performed there: (1) Attach a change event handler to an element; (2) Update the text of an element.  Both of these can certainly be done without jQuery.  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If you encounter a problem with that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, this community can help with that.
